# How should I hang speakers with a keyhole mounting slot?

Tags: home-theater

I have a pair of Sony speakers that I’m not quite too sure on how to hang on my wall. The backs look like this:

[image]

Would I just put a screw in my wall and hang it up like that? Would there be enough room for the speaker wire in the back?

What’s the best/correct method of hanging speakers like this?

Comment: I usually use a wall plate and have the wires hidden , If surface mounting put a screw in the race way and have the wires enter from the back. If not your property just a screw and let the wires hang.

Answer (score 1):

However you like, as long as there's a suitably-sized screw head present.

That slot you see is designed to accept a screw with a head (or similar stud) that fits the wide part and a shaft that fits the small part. As long as you meet those requirements you're good.

Whether you facilitate wire hiding is up to you. Low-voltage boxes and plates can work well, or simply a round grommet set into the wall. Be sure there's not a stud where you cut the hole.

I'd consider putting some felt or silicone pads on the back of the speaker to reduce vibration noise and finish damage.